# Full Text search of content of a pdf file stored in database MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, pdf, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working with an ASP.NET MVC project running on the .NET Framework 4.7.2. I have a database of some pdf documents and a related column description. I want to perform full text Searching in the database so the text in the description column as well as the text of the PDF documents stored in the database are searched for that string value and make a list of all the items (documents and other data that matches the search) return a list.

I searched for this but this made me more confused about indexing and paging in search and How I can perform a search in the database to retrieve the list of matched documents through document content.

Comment: You can read the contents of a PDF with `iTextSharp` and it's `PdfTextExtractor`. If you store that text in the database you could easily search through the pdf contents.

Comment: I have `sql-server` database and an `ASP.Net MVC` framework where I want to place a search box in my code to insert a query and retrieve relevant files(all files that contain that string) from the database stored in `pdf` format. @marc_s